# rosjava test failed to pass

Tags: ros, build, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I followed the instruction on this page
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html
tried to install and build rosjava. Everything went well until the test step. I executed the command "./gradlew test" and got the following failing message:

```
Test org.ros.internal.message.MessageSerializationTest FAILED
131 tests completed, 16 failures

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rosjava:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at /home/iratao/my_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava/build/reports/tests.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Does anyone has an idea about this failure?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34325/rosjava-test-failed-to-pass/) by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2012-05-21**:
same problem here. It seems that the path to /std_msgs/msg/ is not know. At least the report says that 16 messages could not be found.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-05-21**:
Could you add which tests are failing to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I pushed a fix for this yesterday. Please pull and try again.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-05-25**:
Hi Damon. I am still getting two failure cases for
DefaultNodeTest.testCreatePublic  and  NtpTimeProviderTest.testNtpUbuntuCom. for both I am getting java.lang.AssertionError

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-05-26**:
That's expected if you don't have internet access.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-05-28**:
I am also failing on org.ros.time.NtpTimeProviderTest, and I definitely have internet access.  Suggestions?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-05-29**:
It's probably just timing out. It's safe to ignore. The test should be rewritten anyway.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-05-29**:
It seems you are right, everything appears to be working even with this test failure.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having very similar problems, these are the failed tests. In each case, the error is a NoSuchElementException, for example "java.util.NoSuchElementException: Resource does not exist: /std_msgs/msg/Bool.msg"

(I'd post this as a comment but I don't have enough points yet to do so)

```
MessageSerializationTest.testBool
MessageSerializationTest.testDuration
MessageSerializationTest.testFloat32
MessageSerializationTest.testFloat64
MessageSerializationTest.testInt16
MessageSerializationTest.testInt32
MessageSerializationTest.testInt64
MessageSerializationTest.testInt8
MessageSerializationTest.testNestedMessage
MessageSerializationTest.testNestedMessageArray
MessageSerializationTest.testString
MessageSerializationTest.testTime
MessageSerializationTest.testUInt16
MessageSerializationTest.testUInt32
MessageSerializationTest.testUInt64
MessageSerializationTest.testUint8
NtpTimeProviderTest.testSanity
```

---

Originally posted by [azimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2424/azimmerman/) with karma: 11 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-05-24**:
I also got same cases failed. Could this be realted to latest gradle (and its wrapper), I manually have to modify org.gradle.wrapper.Download.java file so that it accepts the proxy needed for downloading : http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip during./gradle install